# How does Django create request.session and interface with WSGI?

Tags: django, wsgi, csrf, swfupload, authentication

I'm working with SWFUpload and Django, and I've noticed that authentication tends to break.

There is one part that is holding me up and I'm looking for direction more then a solution as I think know the solution is not yet available. (So I'm making it. )

I need to know how Django creates the WSGI request-object and how it's handled.

After looking at the source of django, it seems that csrf is done via the WSGIobject which have the appropriate cookeis appended to it. Naturally flash posts do not support this unless specified. SWFUpload offers the ability to send cookie data in the post params via a plugin, however I'd like to send them via headers on the URLRequest object. ( So that the Auth-Middleware and CSRF-Middleware can see it. )

My goal is to upgrade SWFUpload to send headers containing the values for what ever objects I pass it. The hard part for me is to figure out how those headers will be interpreted.

**How does Django create the request.META object? | Where is the request.session object created?**

I'm reading up on the WSGInterface now, but I'd like to accelerate this research. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe what you're looking for is [django.core.handlers.wsgi](http://code.djangoproject.com/browser/django/trunk/django/core/handlers/wsgi.py).